# flutter want to keep sharedpreferences although shutting down the app

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

Currently, my app lost data after closing the app. But I want to keep sharedpreferences data even if the app shut down. Do you know any good way for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shared preferences` does persist the data, so you might be doing something wrong.

Here are other alternatives:
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence

Comment: I decide to change to sqlite. Thank you.